# custom columns on demand using select on OracleDB

Tags: sql, oracle, select

If I have a query returning PARAM_VALUE with multiple values like

| PARAM_VALUE |
| --- |
| 1,2,3,4,5,6 |

How can I return multiple columns on demand using SELECT to present this data like

| PARAM_VALUE1 | PARAM_VALUE2 | PARAM_VALUE3 | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | ... |

Comment: Splitting into multiple *rows* is fairly straightforward; but the SQL parser needs to know the number of *columns* as a fixed value before it starts. You can use dynamic SQL but it's a bit messy - so are you sure that's really what you need? Who/what will consume the result, and how will that cope with an unknown number of columns in the result set?

Answer (score 1):

SQL (not just Oracle) requires a known, fixed number of output columns. So, if you have a fixed maximum number of delimited values in your string then you can use string functions to find the sub-strings:

```sql
SELECT param_value,
       CASE pos1
       WHEN 0
       THEN param_value
       ELSE SUBSTR(param_value, 1, pos1 - 1)
       END AS param_value1,
       CASE 
       WHEN pos1 = 0
       THEN NULL
       WHEN pos2 = 0
       THEN SUBSTR(param_value, pos1 + 1)
       ELSE SUBSTR(param_value, pos1 + 1, pos2 - pos1 - 1)
       END AS param_value2,
       CASE 
       WHEN pos2 = 0
       THEN NULL
       WHEN pos3 = 0
       THEN SUBSTR(param_value, pos2 + 1)
       ELSE SUBSTR(param_value, pos2 + 1, pos3 - pos2 - 1)
       END AS param_value3,
       CASE 
       WHEN pos3 = 0
       THEN NULL
       WHEN pos4 = 0
       THEN SUBSTR(param_value, pos3 + 1)
       ELSE SUBSTR(param_value, pos3 + 1, pos4 - pos3 - 1)
       END AS param_value4
FROM   (
  SELECT param_value,
         INSTR(param_value, ',', 1, 1) AS pos1,
         INSTR(param_value, ',', 1, 2) AS pos2,
         INSTR(param_value, ',', 1, 3) AS pos3,
         INSTR(param_value, ',', 1, 4) AS pos4,
         INSTR(param_value, ',', 1, 5) AS pos5
  FROM   table_name
);
```

or, more compact, but slower, using regular expressions:

```sql
SELECT param_value,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR(param_value, '([^,]*)(,|$)', 1, 1, NULL, 1) AS param_value1,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR(param_value, '([^,]*)(,|$)', 1, 2, NULL, 1) AS param_value2,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR(param_value, '([^,]*)(,|$)', 1, 3, NULL, 1) AS param_value3,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR(param_value, '([^,]*)(,|$)', 1, 4, NULL, 1) AS param_value4
FROM   table_name;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```
create table table_name (param_value) AS
  SELECT NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'A' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'A,B' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'A,B,C' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'A,B,C,D' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'A,B,C,D,E' FROM DUAL;
```

Both output:

| PARAM_VALUE | PARAM_VALUE1 | PARAM_VALUE2 | PARAM_VALUE3 | PARAM_VALUE4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* |
| A | A | *null* | *null* | *null* |
| A,B | A | B | *null* | *null* |
| A,B,C | A | B | C | *null* |
| A,B,C,D | A | B | C | D |
| A,B,C,D,E | A | B | C | D |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/a0qQW-8B)

Comment: what if I don't know the number of output columns? Can this be done dynamically?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to generate the values for an unknown length of list then generate the values as rows (rather than columns):

```sql
SELECT param_value,
       item,
       CASE epos
       WHEN 0
       THEN SUBSTR(param_value, spos)
       ELSE SUBSTR(param_value, spos, epos - spos)
       END AS param
FROM   table_name t
       CROSS APPLY (
         SELECT LEVEL AS item,
                CASE LEVEL
                WHEN 1
                THEN 1
                ELSE INSTR(t.param_value, ',', 1, LEVEL - 1) + 1
                END AS spos,
                INSTR(t.param_value, ',', 1, LEVEL) AS epos
         FROM   DUAL
         CONNECT BY INSTR(t.param_value, ',', 1, LEVEL - 1) > 0
       ) b
```

Which, for the sample data:

```
create table table_name (param_value) AS
  SELECT NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'A' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'A,B' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'A,B,C' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'A,B,C,D' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'A,B,C,D,E' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| PARAM_VALUE | ITEM | PARAM |
| --- | --- | --- |
| *null* | 1 | *null* |
| A | 1 | A |
| A,B | 1 | A |
| A,B | 2 | B |
| A,B,C | 1 | A |
| A,B,C | 2 | B |
| A,B,C | 3 | C |
| A,B,C,D | 1 | A |
| A,B,C,D | 2 | B |
| A,B,C,D | 3 | C |
| A,B,C,D | 4 | D |
| A,B,C,D,E | 1 | A |
| A,B,C,D,E | 2 | B |
| A,B,C,D,E | 3 | C |
| A,B,C,D,E | 4 | D |
| A,B,C,D,E | 5 | E |

If you then want it as columns then transpose the data set in whatever third party application you are using to access the database as it is likely to support the output format you want (whereas it would be very difficult to generate a dynamic output using SQL).

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/EgHfIUuc)

Comment: well, I need to tranpose using SQL. This will be consumed by another system.

Comment: @bmelo Static SQL (of any dialect, not just Oracle) does not support returning a dynamic number of columns. You can try dynamic SQL but it is very messy or you either need to have a fixed number of columns or transpose using another program; what you are asking is something that SQL is not designed to do.